# how can i fix this " valgrind tests failed;"

Tags: valgrind

I got this error while all the `malloc` nodes are freed when I run the Valgrind test:

```
in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
total heap usage: 30 allocs, 30 frees, 7,520 bytes allocated
All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

also this with Valgrind -v test:

```
WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
old: 0x04022e10 (strlen       ) R-> (0000.0) 0x580c9ce2 ???
new: 0x04022e10 (strlen       ) R-> (2007.0) 0x0483f060 strlen
```

and this is the error report :

`Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 95)`

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char TEXT[48];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

//loop over hash buckets
    for (int I = 0; I < N; I++)
    {
        table [I] = malloc(sizeof(node)); <--- line 37
        table [I]-> next = NULL;
    }
```

here is the check function :

```
    int x = hash(word);
    node *check_ptr = table[x];
    int m = strlen(word);

    while (check_ptr != NULL )
    {
        int n = strlen(check_ptr -> TEXT);<----- line 91

           "some code "
    }
```

UPDATE - more detailed message

```
by 0x401C57: check (dictionary.c:91) 
---- by 0x40160B: main (speller.c:113) 
---- Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
 ---- by 0x4019C6: load (dictionary.c:37)
 --- by 0x4012CE: main (speller.c:40)

 WORDS IN TEXT: 10

HEAP SUMMARY: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ---- total heap usage: 143,122 allocs, 143,122 frees, 8,024,712 bytes allocated
All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
 ---- ERROR SUMMARY: 10 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Which is line 95?

Comment: int n = strlen(check_ptr -> TEXT);

Comment: Can you run with `--track-origins=yes` and update your question?

Comment: Look at dictionary.c line 37 and make sure that everything that is allocated there is initialized and also stays initialized.

Comment: by 0x401C57: check (dictionary.c:91)// 
by 0x40160B: main (speller.c:113)//
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd4-linux.so// 
by 0x4019C6: load (dictionary.c:37)//
by 0x4012CE: main (speller.c:40)//
WORDS IN TEXT: 10//
HEAP SUMMARY:
in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks//
total heap usage: 143,122 allocs, 143,122 frees, 8,024,712 bytes allocated All heap// blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible// 
ERROR SUMMARY: 10 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)//

Comment: Please edit the original question. It's very hard to read code and logs in these comments.

Comment: i added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

```
//loop over hash buckets to initialize the all the buckets to contain null TEXT value  solves the problem 
it was because i never initialized the TEXT values while i was trying to access them later in the code.


for (int I = 0; I < N; I++)
{
    table [I] = malloc(sizeof(node));
    table [I]-> next = NULL;
    **for (int u =0; u< 48 ; u++)
    {
        table [I]-> TEXT[u] = '0';
    }**

}
```